# Nginx redirect Wordpress categories and tags

Tags: wordpress, nginx, url-rewriting

I have a wordpress site and I want to change the category and tag base from default to /t/

Right now I have:

```
 site.com/category/A
 site.com/category/B

 site.com/tag/C
 site.com/tag/D
```

I want the url to be:

```
 site.com/t/A
 site.com/t/B
 site.com/t/C
 site.com/t/D
```

I know how to do it one by one, but I have a lot of category and tag pages, is there a way to do a group redirect, with a global rule or something?

Comment: Is doing this at wordpress level any of interest to you ? Or do you want both to be accessible? site.com/t/A and  site.com/category/A

Comment: Something like: `rewrite ^/(category|tag)/(.*)$ /t/$2 permanent;`

Comment: @CptChix I only want site.com/t/A to be accessible, site.com/category/A should be redirect to site.com/t/A. I want to do this at nginx level, because it is faster

Answer (score 1):

I decided to not go forward with this change.

For anyone who is looking to do the same thing, don't.
If we use the same base for category and tag, then wordpress would not be able to tell if a url is for category or tag, category will continue to work, but tag will result in 404.

Thanks to Richard Smith and CptChix for helping.